# Cleanly create new instances of a type using values in an existing instance

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn Scala and am attempting to adhere to the immutable principle when creating objects.

I have a Scala class defined as:

```
class TDay(date: LocalDate, open: Double, high: Double,
           low: Double, close: Double, tr1: Double = 0.0, tr14: Double = 0.0)
{

}
```

The parameters `date, open, high, low` and `close` are all values I know at the time of creation of any `TDay` instance but `tr1` and `tr14` are values that are to be calculated and `tr1` is calculated from `open, high, low` and `close` and `tr14` is calculated from a series of `tr1` values retrieved from other `TDay` instances.

If I were coding this in Java I would happily calculate the value of `tr1` and `tr14` and place them into the **same** object. But if I am to do this 'the Scala way' I assume would need to create new `TDay` instances  each time I want to calculate `tr1` or `tr14` for a given `TDay` instance.

I could overload the `TDay` constructor:

```
def this(tDay: TDay, tr1: Double)
    {
        this(tDay.date, tDay.open, tDay.high, tDay.low, tDay.close,
        tr1, tDay.tr14)
    }
```

But that means I have already defined a constructor of signature `(TDay, Double)` so cannot overload again to set the value of `tr14`. In fact my example here is simplified and I have several more `Double` values I need to calculate and set each one needing to be done in a specific order.

Is there a clean way to create a new instance of `TDay` using values from one that already exists and setting the newly calculated value at the same time without the code becoming verbose? Or does the way I approach the problem require a re-think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a `case class`, which would be the usual way to represent a simple record like this:

```
case class TDay(date: LocalDate, open: Double, high: Double,
                low: Double, close: Double, tr1: Double = 0.0, tr14: Double = 0.0)
```

Then you can use the `copy` method to create a copy with updated elements:

```
val td: TDay = ...
val tdNew = td.copy(tr1 = ..., tr14 = ...)
```

Comment: You had the right idea. In fact, the idea was so good that the designers of Scala also thought it was a good idea and auto-generated this method for you.